# copy each file to user-defined targets

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

source_files=/home/softwares

for file in $(ls $source_files)
do
echo -n "Enter destination directory for $file: "; read destdir

cp -r $file $destdir
done
```

I have small scripts to copy the file from one place to another place with, this will ask users to enter the destination location where do you want to copy the files.

After giving the inputs from the users its throwing the below error.

```
bash -x test.sh 
+ source_files=/home/softwares
++ ls /home/softwares
+ for file in $(ls $source_files)
+ echo -n 'Enter destination directory for a.txt: '
Enter destination directory for a.txt: + read destdir
/opt/java
+ cp -r a.txt /opt/java
cp: cannot stat 'a.txt': No such file or directory
```

Note: I have folder /opt/java in my machine, can you please help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are running

```
ls $source_files
```

this gives you the file paths relative to the `$source_files` directory.
You should use that same path when copying:

```
cp -r $source_files/$file $destdir
```

Answer (score 4):

That's [why you should never parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Here is a working version:

```
#!/bin/bash

source_files=/home/softwares

for file in "$source_files"/*; do
    read -r -p "Enter destination directory for $file: " destdir
    cp -r "$file" "$destdir"
done
```

Comment: clean and complete solution.

Comment: Hi Chris & Ismail, thanks lot for timely response, its working as i expected, i love stack-overflow users.